# RSA encryption. EVP_PKEY_CTX_new failed

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I am implementing RSA encryption with OAEP SHA256.
Following samples on stackoverflow and openssl docs,
I implemented below code.But I failed to find why EVP_PKEY_size and EVP_PKEY_CTX_new() are failing.

Can anyone point the mistake? or can anyone provide a code which can do SHA256 rsa public key encryption?

```
   keybio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    if (keybio == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to create key BIO");
        return 0;
    }
    int len = BIO_write(keybio, Key, strlen(Key));
    EVP_PKEY*  evppubKey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(keybio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
//  EVP_PKEY* evp_key = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(keybio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    int a = EVP_PKEY_size(evp_key);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX* ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(evp_key, eng);
    
    EVP_PKEY_free(evp_key);

    if (ctx)
    {
        if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init(ctx) > 0)
        {
            EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl_str(ctx, "rsa_padding_mode", "oaep");
            EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl_str(ctx, "rsa_oaep_md", "sha256");
            EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl_str(ctx, "rsa_mgf1_md", "sha256");


            if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt(ctx, NULL, &outlen, data, data_len) <= 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            outdata = OPENSSL_malloc(outlen);

            if (!outdata) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (EVP_PKEY_encrypt(ctx, outdata, &outlen, data, data_len) <= 0) {
                return -1;
            }

        }
        EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);
    }
```

Update:
I made changes to code. PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY() returning NULL.
My public starts with -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- I am not sure if PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY() is right method to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's the type.**

`PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY` takes by reference (if nonnull) AND returns `RSA *` not `EVP_PKEY *`; see the man page on your system or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY.html). Using the wrong pointed-to type violates a constraint in C, and if you use a decent compiler in conforming mode (which is almost always a good idea) it should have given you diagnostics, which you should have paid attention to.

Similarly, `RSA_size` requires `RSA *` which you actually have not `EVP_PKEY *` as you falsely declared and thus works,  but `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new` requires `EVP_PKEY *` which you don't have and thus doesn't work. If you had been luckier it would have at least crashed, or given you nasal demons or reformatted your disk.

The simplest solution is to use `PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY` (note NO `RSA`), also on that same man page, which takes&returns `EVP_PKEY *` -- and don't call `RSA_size` on it. If you actually need the output size or key size, which it doesn't appear you do, use `EVP_PKEY_size` or `EVP_PKEY_bits` as appropriate.

Alternatively you could use an `RSA *` for the result of `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY` and then set it into a separately allocated `EVP_PKEY *` to use for the encryption. This will work but is more fiddly.

Added: Also you need to use `EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init` NOT `_decrypt_init` for `EVP_PKEY_encrypt`,

> I have access only to pub key, not to .pem file

The extension on a file doesn't matter in itself, only in that it is commonly used to indicate the content of the file. PEM *format* (in a file) can be used for many kinds of data, including a public key, in fact `PEM_read_[bio]_[type]_PUBKEY` reads exactly that: a PEM file (or other data source) containing a public key. If that's not what you have, your code is much more wrong than I diagnosed above, but since since you don't say what you do have it's impossible to give any useful advice. If you mean you have the *private key* in a PEM file, and want the public key, use `openssl rsa -in private -pubout -out public` or `openssl pkey -in private -pubout -out public`.  OpenSSL actually can encrypt with the private key, since the private key value fully determines the public key, but any system that uses keys that way is badly designed and probably insecure.

---

**UPDATE:** you now disclose your file contains `-----BEGIN/END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`. This is a very rarely used format that is NOT the format that OpenSSL calls 'PUBKEY', which is the SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure from X.509/PKIX and is labelled `-----BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY-----` (no 'RSA' even though it *contains* an RSA publickey). To read your file you must use (as you had in a comment) `PEM_read_[bio]_RSAPublicKey` -- which takes&returns `RSA *` not `EVP_PKEY *`. There is no capability to read this type of file as `EVP_PKEY *`, but since you need `EVP_PKEY *` for the encrypt routines you want, you must use the 'alternative' I mentioned previously: first read the file into an `RSA *`, then build an `EVP_PKEY *` from that `RSA *`:

```
...
RSA * rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey (bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if( rsa == NULL ) error;
EVP_PKEY * evp_key = EVP_PKEY_new();
if( evp_key == NULL ) error; // very unlikely
if( ! EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA (evp_key, rsa) ) error;
RSA_free (rsa);
// and then continue as you already have:
EVP_PKEY_CTX* ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(evp_key, eng/*normally NULL*/);
if nonnull and EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init(ctx) > 0:
  EVP_PKEY_CTX_ctrl ... and EVP_PKEY_encrypt
```

Comment: Helpful link for [nasal demons: n.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Comment: @David C. Rankin  : I don't see anything related to my question in the above link

Comment: @TippuR that was a link for the author to explain *"or given you nasal demons or reformatted your disk."*...